# Why is heading tucked under previous div element?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to style the page http://techno-french.com/french-news-room and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the H1 heading,

*Learn French Online Free with Mots de L’actu*

is partly obscured by the right floated div above it. I have tried putting 2em of bottom margin on the Div above, and then tried putting top margin on the Div containing the Heading. It works fine in [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) outside of [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), so I suspect the CSS is right, but inside of WordPress, the heading slips under the Div above it. I'm not expert, but this seems to be coded correctly:

Here's the code:

```
<div style="float: left; width:360px; height:467px;">
   <h2 style="text-align: center;">Top Stories: Le Progres</h2>
   [WordPress shortcode for an advanced iFrame]
</div>
<div style="float: right; width:517px; height:560px; margin-bottom: 2em;">
   <h2>Funny Helps Learning</h2>
   [WordPress shortcode for an advanced iFrame}
</div>
<div style="float: left; clear: both;">
   <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #0b00dd;">Learn French Online 
      Free with Mots de  L'actu
   </h1>
   TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: why height is different for both the div's?

Comment: I am using a Wordpress plugin called Advanced IFrame which allows me to cut a "slice" of a certain height and width out of another website and display it in an Iframe.  I try to make the Div dimensions the same as the slice, otherwise the section of the website, viewed in the iframe, tends to "drift"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you left and right float div's into another div and add clearfix to it. It should work fine.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
   <div style="float: left; width:360px; height:467px;">

   <h2 style="text-align: center;">Top Stories: Le Progres</h2>

   [Wordpress shortcode for an advanced iFrame]

   </div>

   <div style="float: right; width:517px; height:560px; margin-bottom: 2em;">

   <h2>Funny Helps Learning</h2>

   [Wordpress shortcode for an advanced iFrame}

   </div>
</div>

<div style="float: left; clear: both;">

<h1 style="text-align: center; color: #0b00dd;">Learn French Online 
Free with Mots de  L'actu</h1>

TEXT

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="ai-div-news7">` is set to height 560px as is its parent div, but above `#ai-div-news7` there is an `<h2>` that is forcing `#ai-div-news7` down.

Please view the console for that website and also visit [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftechno-french.com%2Ffrench-news-room&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Changing `<div style="float: right; width:517px; height:560px; margin-bottom: 2em;">` to `<div style="float: right; width:517px; margin-bottom: 2em;">` fixes the problem.

Comment: What console?  This is a Wordpress site.  I have either the HTML or the Visual versions when creating a post.  I'm not sure what you mean. Also, I think the ID ai-div-news7 is coming from the "iframed" site, not mine, and so I have no control over that.

Comment: Sorry, by console I meant the JavaScript console in the browser you are using. There were over 20 errors showing up when I viewed your site, some of which were coming from the "iframed" content.

Comment: Making the change you recommended DID work, but would you mind explaining why?  The ID you mentioned is from the Iframed site, since I use only inline styles.  So, having the h2 within the Div pushes down the ai-div-news7 Div WITHIN the Iframe?  Would it also work to include the H2 by itself outside of the Div (or in its own Div?) containing the Iframe?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the console.

Comment: By not specifying a height for the `<div>` we allow the div to set its own height based on the height of the content. When that `<div>` has the right height it allows the previously overwritten header to be positioned lower down.